# Rational number not correctly convert to float

Tags: ruby

RUBY_VERSION 2.2.0-preview1

```
Rational('19/2') # => (19/2) = `.to_f` => 9.5, correct!
Rational(19, 2)  # => (19/2) = `.to_f` => 9.5, correct!

Rational(19/2) # => (9/1) = `.to_f` => 9.0, ???????????????
(19/2).to_r => (9/1), ???????
(19/2).rationalize => (9/1), ??????
```

For those ???????, I am wondering WHY?

Source of [rational](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/rational.c)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have `(19/2)` anywhere in that code that's not in a string, and that includes in the call to `Rational()`, Ruby is evaluating the integer division before passing anything to Rational. And in Ruby, integer division returns an integer. In IRB:

```
2.0.0p0 :001 > 19/2
 => 9 
2.0.0p0 :002 > 19.0/2
 => 9.5 
2.0.0p0 :003 > (19.0/2).to_r
 => (19/2)
```

This is a rather odd behavior that Ruby inherited from C where the result of integer division is always an integer. So, in the end, the only value that the Rational class ever sees is `9`, which it rightly converts to `9/1`.

Comment: @juanitofatas: Sure. It's not that hard to get used to, but if you don't know about it, it can make you struggle a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Because `19 / 2 == 9`.

You're passing in 9 to `Rational`.

Answer (score 2):

Because the integer division `19 / 2 => 9` was performed *prior* to sending the value to `Rational`.

Answer (score 1):

What Ruby is doing is performing **integer division**. That is dividing an integer by another integer.

```
19/2
```

2 goes into 19 9 times. Because both the numerator and denominator are both integers, Ruby will return 9.

If you would like to return a floating point number, you need to use **floatation division**.

```
19.0/2
```

Since the numerator is now a floating point number, Ruby knows to perform floatation division. Ruby will return the correct answer of 9.5 in this case.